# Open MvvmCross app via link with data

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, mvvmcross, intentfilter

In native Android apps you can define an `intent-filter` for an activity in the Manifest file which can open the app when a specific link (e.g. `myprotocol://mysite.com/action/data`) is visited from a website or email.

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="myprotocol" android:host="mysite.com"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

When I try to add this to the AndroidManifest file in an MvvmCross application, it seems that only the view gets loaded, without ViewModel linked to it. I cannot seem to find any information on how to load the ViewModel and get my intent data (the `data` part of the url).

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an app that responds to scanning NFC tags and I have a similar situation.

My solution is to add the following in my `OnCreate` override right after I call `base.OnCreate(bundle)`:

```
if (null == ViewModel)
{
    //This should only happen when the Intent is not an Mvx one. I.e. when having scanned
    //NFC tag. We need to load the ViewModel manually.
    var loaderService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
    ViewModel = (ScanViewModel) loaderService.LoadViewModel(
        new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof (ScanViewModel), null, null, null), null);
}
```

As the comment says, the Intent is not one coming from MvvmCross. This means the bundle which tells MvvmCross which ViewModel to load is not present. So what I do is to create the ViewModel myself.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in the right direction. Although when I try to go to my view from an URL intent-filter, MvvmCross says: `OnViewNewIntent called - but this is not fully handled wihtin MvvmCross currently.`, and it doesn't seem to go directly to the activity with the specified data.

Comment: Did you set any LaunchModes on your Activity? I use `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop` along with `ClearTaskOnLaunch = true`

Comment: I managed to get it right by starting in another Activity and then going to the right view and passing the data. Thanks for the help though.